# Google Photos Faces filter does not appear

Tags: facial-recognition, google-photos

Google's help section regarding "Find faces" says:

1. Go to photos.google.com/search.
2. Under the People section, click a person's face to see photos that include similar faces.
   (If you don't see the person you're looking for, click MORE.)

When I go to the search section, I see "Places" and "Things" - no faces!
And I'm sure I have faces, I used Google+ until now with plenty of face-tagging.

Which also brings up an interesting point - how do you face-tag in this new interface?

Comment: @AlE. The Faces option is also missing from the Google Photos iOS or Android apps, for me (in the UK).

Comment: Maybe it's a location thing.

Comment: Maybe it is. I'm in Israel

Comment: The Support page for this does say it is not available in all countries.

Comment: Correct. Too bad because the faces feature worked fine under the Google+ and Picasa brands.

Comment: @nute As my advice helped you resolve it, did you want to mark it as the answer?

Comment: @ale I'm in the United States.  If it isn't available in the U.S. *where on Earth* would it be available?!

Comment: it is bcz u could have turned off face recognition in settings and now all faces are gone same thing happened with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to enable it by dialling into a US VPN (or going to the USA) and enabling the feature.

I found out about it from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/37uepw/is_face_recognition_in_the_new_google_photos_app/

On Android, you can download a VPN client and run all of the device communication through the VPN.

On iOS, nute (the OP) travelled to the USA and enabled it there, so I can't currently confirm if the VPN settings work on iOS.

Instructions:

**Android**

1. Download the app "Psiphon" and activate it to a US VPN.
2. Go to the Android Settings > Applications > Downloaded > Photos.
3. Hit the "clear data" button (this just clears the local app's data, not photos).
4. Sign into Photos (it should take you through the signup process).
5. Go to the Photos Settings and hit the now showing "Group Similar Faces" button.
6. Validate that people show on the device, or another client (web for example).
7. Turn off and uninstall Phison (if you want).

**iOS**

1. Activate the VPN within Settings > General > VPN and set to a USA VPN
2. (If you already have the Photos app) delete the Photos app
3. Download the Photos app
4. Sign into Photos
5. Go into Settings and enable the now showing "Group similar Faces" option.
6. Validate on the device (or web app) that people now show.
7. Disable the VPN if desired.

Comment: Anyone able to confirm on iPhone? Does not seem to work for me. I happen to be traveling to the US, I removed my account and re added it but it does not appear.

Comment: I deleted completely the application and re-installed it while traveling to the U.S.  It worked, it showed the option to group faces. Now I'm back home and so far it's still there.

Comment: Yes, I believe there's no iOS equivalent to "Delete App Data" so it makes sense if it requires a delete and re-install. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I see the "group similar faces" option and enabled it, but no People in search :-( Only "places" and "things"

Comment: @Michael Oh no! Hope they haven't changed it! As long as you see the option, it should show. Have you tried exiting, and going back in? Clearing the app cache etc?

Comment: Tried all of these. Also doesn't show on web